# VBA If function with Vlookup

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, vlookup, vba

I am trying to use a formula that states the following:

If A4 = T Then Vlookup
Else Vlookup2

Here is what I have written that it does not like.

=IF(A4 = "T","=VLOOKUP(I4,treatlookup,11,FALSE)","=VLOOKUP(I4,itemlookup,22,FALSE)")

I tried without the quotes around the =Vlookup but it does not accept that either, gives an error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe this:`=IF(A4 = "T",VLOOKUP(I4,treatlookup,11,FALSE),VLOOKUP(I4,itemlookup,22,FALSE))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the value as you would typing in the formula into the cell. Removing the `"` and `=` should resolve your problem:

```
=IF(A4="T",VLOOKUP(I4,treatlookup,11,FALSE),VLOOKUP(I4,itemlookup,22,FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks, should have caught that.

Comment: @SASUSMC, or little shorter `=VLOOKUP(I4,treatlookup,IF(A4="T",11,22),FALSE)` :)

Comment: Ok, now I am getting an object defined error when I use the function.  It just does not like something about it.

Comment: @SASUSMC you need to provide more details otherwise its not clear what is wrong. I've tested the cell formula I provided and it works. Your defined range `treatlookup` might be the issue.

Comment: @simoco I'm not sure that's correct since he's defined two ranges for lookup: `treatlookup` if true and `itemlookup` if false. Your suggestion only considers `treatlookup`.